# Bash - piping awk result to variable

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I'm new to bash, and I've literally spent hours trying to figure this out but I'm stuck.

I'm writing a script which will auto-execute upon completion of a download in pyLoad. I need to check if the first word of the package name is "Public".

Whilst trying to debug, I've gotten this so far:

```
#!/bin/sh
PACKAGE="$1"
PATH="$2"

FIRST=$(echo $PACKAGE|awk '{print $1}')
echo "First word is: $FIRST"
```

Running this by means of `sh download.sh "test package" ~/` returns

```
download.sh: 5: download.sh: awk: not found
```

I get the same result whether "test package" is in quotes or not.

My aim is to get to something like this:

```
if [ $FIRST == "public"  ]
then
    # Move to public folder
else
    # Do nothing
fi
```

Any help would be appreciated.

OS: Ubuntu 12.04 x64

PATH = `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

awk: not found

because you redefine PATH variable. Try use another name for your internal PATH variable.

Comment: I've not redefined the PATH variable, that's my default one that is outputted if I type echo $PATH in terminal. Sorry for any confusion

Comment: I am talking about 'PATH="$2"'. awk: not found error will be fixed if you rename this variable. I can't understand purpose of PATH in your script because it not used in current fragment.

Comment: Changed it to FPATH (filepath for the download). My existing code works perfectly now. So now I feel like a total idiot.

Comment: get out of the habit of using VARIABLES in caps. Let the system use those.

Answer (score 0):

You can have other options:

```
[[ $PACKAGE =~ ^[[:space:]]*([^[:space:]]+) ]]
FIRST=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
echo "First word is: $FIRST"
```

Or

```
FIRST=${PACKAGE%%[[:space:]]*}
echo "First word is: $FIRST"
```

Comment: I used the second one, it works perfectly. Any chance you could explain what it's doing? 
From what I can tell, it's reading the PACKAGE variable (even though there's no $ before it), then does something with regex to split the string by spaces. But how does it only return the first word?

Comment: For the first version, it makes use of Regex matching. Everything that is matched by the pattern is saved in `BASH_REMATCH[0]`. And every other matches that are placed inside () are saved in `BASH_REMATCH[1]`, `BASH_REMATCH[2]`, and so on depending on the number of (). And that is why the first word is saved in `BASH_REMATCH[1]`. For the second one, it uses special parameter expansion with syntax of `${parameter%%word}`. It deletes the match by a glob pattern (not regex). You can read more about it [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).